# Set EditText Digits Programatically with Filters

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the digits value of an EditText programatically with pattern "9,999" (where 9 it's digit 0-9). So far I have:

```
final EditText editText =  new EditText(v.getContext());
editText.setLayoutParams(params);
editText.setText("");
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLenght)});
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    int len=0;
    //int count=0;

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
         String str = editText.getText().toString(); 
         if(str.length()==1&& len <str.length()){//len check for backspace 
             editText.append(",");
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
         String str = editText.getText().toString(); 
         len = str.length();
     }

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
         String str = editText.getText().toString();
     }     
});
```

Which is not best, because:

- DigitsKeyListener won't accept "," separator.
- When I type "1,0" and
  then go 2x backspace I can type "11111". I have to go 3x backspace
  and then when I type "11111" it will be "1,1111"

Any ideas?

Comment: check this link might help , http://blog.roshka.com/2012/08/android-edittext-with-number-format.html , you can update the class to the desired format you want, hope that will help , if so let me know to post the answer if I may do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing `afterTextChange()` method to this

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    try {
        String str = String.format("%,d", Long.parseLong(s.toString()
                .replaceAll(",", "")));
        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();

        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.setText(str);
        editText.setSelection(pos);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```